# Am I using inheritance, borrowed pointers, and explicit lifetime annotations correctly?

Tags: memory-management, rust

I'm learning Rust, coming from an almost exclusively garbage collected background. So I want to make sure I'm getting off on the right foot as I write my first program.

The tutorial on the Rust site said I should be dubious of using pointers that aren't `&`. With that in mind, here's what I ended up with in my little class hierarchy (names changed to protect innocent). The gist is, I have two different entities, let's say `Derived1` and `Derived2`, which share some behavior and structure. I put the common data into a `Foo` struct and common behavior into a `Fooish` trait:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    name:       &'a str,
    an_array:   &'a [AnEnumType],
    /* etc. */
}

struct Derived1<'a> {
    foo:         &'a Foo<'a>,
    other_stuff: &'a str,
}
struct Derived2<'a> {
    foo: &'a Foo<'a>,
    /* etc. */
}

trait Fooish<'a> {
    fn new(foo: &'a Foo<'a>) -> Self;
    /* etc. */
}

impl<'a> Fooish<'a> for Derived1<'a> {
    fn new(foo: &'a Foo<'a>) -> Derived1<'a> {
        Derived1 { foo: foo, other_stuff: "bar" }
    }
    /* etc. */
}

/* and so forth for Derived2 */
```

My questions:

1. Am I "doing inheritance in Rust" more-or-less idiomatically?
2. Is it correct to use `&` pointers as struct fields here? (such as for string data, and array fields whose sizes vary from instance to instance? What about for `Foo` in `Derived`?)
3. If the answer to #2 is 'yes', then I need explicit lifetime annotations, right?
4. Is it common to have so many lifetime annotations everywhere as in my example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that this is not idiomatic at all, but sometimes there *are* tasks which require stepping away from idiomatic approaches, it is just not clear if this is really such a case.

I'd suggest you to refrain from using ideas from OO languages which operate in terms of classes and inheritance - they won't work correctly in Rust. Instead you should think of your data in terms of *ownership*: ask yourself a question, should the given struct *own* the data? In other words, does the data belong to the struct naturally or it can be used independently somewhere?

If you apply this reasoning to your structures:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    name:       &'a str,
    an_array:   &'a [AnEnumType],
    /* etc. */
}

struct Derived1<'a> {
    foo:         &'a Foo<'a>,
    other_stuff: &'a str,
}

struct Derived2<'a> {
    foo: &'a Foo<'a>,
    /* etc. */
}
```

you would see that it doesn't really make sense to encode inheritance using references. If `Derived1` has a reference to `Foo`, then it is implied that this `Foo` is created somewhere else, and `Derived1` is only borrowing it for a while. While this *may* be something you really want, this is not how inheritance works: inherited structures/classes usually *contain* their "parent" contents inside them; in other words, they *own* their parent data, so this will be more appropriate structure:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    name:       &'a str,
    an_array:   &'a [AnEnumType],
    /* etc. */
}

struct Derived1<'a> {
    foo:         Foo<'a>
    other_stuff: &'a str,
}

struct Derived2<'a> {
    foo: Foo<'a>,
    /* etc. */
}
```

Note that `Derived*` structures now include `Foo` into them.

As for strings and arrays (string slices and array slices in fact), then yes, if you want to hold them in structures you do have to use lifetime annotations. However, it does not happen that often, and, again, designing structures based on ownership usually helps to decide whether this should be a slice or a dynamically allocated `String` or `Vec`. There is a [nice tutorial on strings](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-strings.html), which explains, among everything else, when you need to use owned strings and when you need slices. Same reasoning applies to `&[T]`/`Vec<T>`. In short, if your struct *owns* the string/array, you have to use `String`/`Vec`. Otherwise, consider using slices.